# WSO2 SSL private key from freessl.com

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have got my private key and certificate from sslforfree.com.I have not created from a CSR or private key from WSO2.
I have gotten directly private key and certicate from sslforfree.com 
I have installed certificate and key in WSO2 and SSL is working fine.But i am getting an exception like

[2017-02-22 06:35:20,018] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.UserRealmProxy} -  Error while encrypting the Credential for User Name asasa
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error while encrypting the Credential for User Name asasa
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.callSecure(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:168)
  Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error while encrypting the Credential for User Name asasa
        at

Can WSO2 accept private key from another party?Could it be the reason for this error?

Comment: post entire exception trace.

Comment: how did you install the private/public key?

Comment: I reinstalled everything. Earlier I was using a private key and certificate from a free party without using CSR.Now I made a CSR from WSO2 and generated certificate using free party.Now it works fine for me after reinstall.
I cant no longer replicate this.Thank You